# Layout with 'maps' package

Tags: r

I am having some trouble with getting a certain plot layout when using the maps package. Here is what I am attempting:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
aa <- rep(1,5); ab <- c(2,3,1,1,1)
mat <- rbind(aa,aa,aa,ab)
layout(mat)
map('state', mar=c(0,0,0,0))
map('worldHires', region='USA:Alaska', xlim=c(-175,-120))
map('worldHires', region='Hawaii', xlim=c(-161,-154.5))
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
Error in plot.new() : plot region too large
```

Usually I mess with the margins to resolve this error, but that doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve this by setting the margins before plotting each new map:

```
layout(mat)
map('state')
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
map('worldHires', region='USA:Alaska', xlim=c(-175,-120), col="blue")
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
map('worldHires', region='Hawaii', xlim=c(-161,-154.5), col="blue")
```

[image]

---

via https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-September/113030.html