# Create an inset map within a larger map in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, maps

I'm trying to make a map of my field sites with an inset map of the maritime provinces in Canada.  So far I have the following:

## Field site map

```
map("worldHires", "Canada", xlim=c(-65.5,-64), ylim=c(45.5,46.35), col="gray90", fill=TRUE)
box(which="plot", lty="solid")
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
points(coord$long, coord$lat, col=coord$sp, pch=20, cex=0.75)
legend(-65.5, 46.35, c("BARS, CLSW & TRES", "BANS", "TRES"), col=c(2,1,3), pch=20, cex=0.75)
```

coord$long and coord$lat are my lat and long coordinates for each site, and coord$sp indicates in the species at each site.

## Inset map of the maritimes

```
map("worldHires", "Canada", xlim=c(-68,-59.9), ylim=c(43.5,48), col="gray90", fill=TRUE)
box(which="plot", lty="solid")
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
rect(-65.5, 45.5, -64, 46.35, angle=45)
```

I'm having issues with getting the inset map into the bottom left corner of the field site map.  I've looked at the following options:

1. layout() option from this question ([Layout with 'maps' package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112867/layout-with-maps-package)), but this doesn't place the inset map inside my other map
2. par(usr=) option from this question (http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/inset-one-map-on-top-of-another-map-td3848752.html), but I don't know how the values for the calculation were determined
3. par(plt=) option from this example (http://wiki.cbr.washington.edu/qerm/sites/qerm/images/7/78/MakingAnInsetMapShorter.r), but again, I don't know how the values were determine.

One of the potentially confounding issues is that the code I am using above to create these maps may not be using the entire plotting window - but I'm not sure how to change that either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been abandoned for nearly three years. But, I believe it is worth providing an answer since there has not been enough information on how to draw inset maps on stack overflow.

I chose ggplot2 to handle this task. First, I downloaded a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame using `getData()` in the `raster` package. I converted the data to a regular data frame, which is require for ggplot. Then, I drew the main map (i.e., `g1`). I used `geom_blank()` in order to provide longitude and latitude for ggplot. It used to be the case that we could add long and lat in `geom_map()`, but the current version of ggplot does not accept long and lat as x and y, respectively. I trimmed the map using `scale_x_continuous()` and `scale_y_continuous()`. Then, I drew the inset map (i.e., `g2`). Since I needed to draw a rectangular, I created a data frame called `temp`. I drew the map in a similar way. Make sure that you treat the inset map as a brow object; you need to use `ggplotGrob()`. The last step is to add the inset map in the main map. You need to identify the best location. You want to play with long and lat values.

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

mydata <- getData("GADM", country = "canada", level = 1)
mymap <- fortify(mydata)

g1 <-  ggplot() +
       geom_blank(data = mymap, aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
       geom_map(data = mymap, map = mymap,
                 aes(group = group, map_id = id),
                 fill = "#b2b2b2", color = "black", size = 0.3) +
       scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-65.5, -64), expand = c(0, 0)) +
       scale_y_continuous(limits = c(45.5, 46.35), expand = c(0, 0)) +
       theme_map()


temp <- data.frame(long = c(-65.5, -65.5, -64, -64, -65.5),
                   lat = c(45.5, 46.35, 46.35, 45.5, 45.5))

g2 <- ggplotGrob(
      ggplot() +
      geom_blank(data = mymap, aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
      geom_map(data = mymap, map = mymap,
               aes(group = group, map_id = id),
               fill = "#b2b2b2", color = "black", size = 0.3) +
      geom_path(data = temp, aes(x = long, y = lat), size = 0.3) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-68, -59.9), expand = c(0, 0)) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(43.5, 48), expand = c(0, 0)) +
      coord_map("polyconic") +
      theme_map() +
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NULL))
      )

g3 <- g1 +
      annotation_custom(grob = g2, xmin = -65.49, xmax = -65.1,
                        ymin = 46.05, ymax = 46.34)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I was never able to figure this out, eventually gave up and just used powerpoint to add an inset map, so your reply is still pertinent to me (and hopefully others)!

Comment: @user3220999 I see. I wish I saw this question earlier. If you still need to do similar tasks, I hope this answer will help you. :)